# wp email publishing with custom content type?

Tags: wordpress

having researched wp forums and only found people asking this question without any answers, I resort to the source of all truth (stack overflow).

I use wordpress custom post types (Custom Post Type UI plugin) and find it very handy.

Now, I want to be able to email-publish some content via WPs built-in email publishing system, but by default that is set up to only publish as regular posts.

I am aware that I can choose categories for the emailed content, but I would very much like to keep all the pages and content of my news (=blogposts) feeds the way they are, being able to put the email-published content into a content type of its own would really help me out.

So I wonder if anyone has done that, and how you would go about it. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps people looking for a solution, but I managed to do it like this...

When a post is submitted for publish by WordPress default email2post, there is an action hook named '`publish_phone`' running, so you can get the post there and change its type like this:

```
add_action('publish_phone','custom_type_by_mail');
function custom_type_by_mail($post_id){
    $p = get_post($post_id,'ARRAY_A');
    $p['post_type'] = "my-custom-type";
    wp_update_post($p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to converting it into a post category instead of its own content type. I know not whether there be any other solution =)